# How to use isLoading with a viewModel and an Environment Object

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, combine

I am using an isLoading Bool in an environment object named authState.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import Combine

class AuthState: ObservableObject {
    
    enum AuthStateMode {
        case unregistered
        case signedInAnonymously
        case signedInWithEmail
    }
    
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var authStateMode: AuthStateMode = .unregistered
    @Published var error: AuthError?
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    
    let authService = AuthService()
    
    init() {
        authService.authStateSubject.assign(to: &$user)
        $user.map { user -> AuthStateMode in
            if let user = user {
                if user.email != nil { return .signedInWithEmail }
                else if user.uid != "" { return .signedInAnonymously }
                else { return .unregistered }
            } else { return .unregistered }
        }.assign(to: &$authStateMode)
    
    }
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        self.isLoading = true
        authService.signIn(email: email, password: password)
            .sink { completion in
                self.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case let .failure(error):
                    return self.error = error
                case .finished: return print("authState.signIn finished")
                }
            } receiveValue: { _ in }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func signInAnonymously() {
        isLoading = true
        authService.signInAnonymously()
            .sink { completion in
                self.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case let .failure(error):
                    return self.error = error
                case .finished: return
                }
            } receiveValue: { user in
                self.user = user
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func linkAccount(email: String, password: String) {
        isLoading = true
        authService.linkAccount(email: email, password: password)
            .sink { completion in
                self.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case let .failure(error):
                    return self.error = error
                case .finished:
                    return print("linkAccount finished")
                }
            } receiveValue: { user in
                self.user = user
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

I have a parent View that uses the authState.isLoading Bool.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct SelectUserTypeView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authState: AuthState

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                if authState.isLoading == true {
                    ProgressView()
                } else if authState.authStateMode == .unregistered {
                    Button { authState.signInAnonymously() }
                        label:{ Text("Connect") }
                } else {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: GuestPreviewView(),
                        label: { Text("Join as Guest") })
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: SignInUpView(viewModel: .init(mode: .signUp)),
                        label: { Text("Host a Session") })
                }
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: RecordingsView(),
                               label: { Text("Browse Recordings") })
                Spacer()
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Welcome to Fullres"), displayMode: .inline)
                    .onAppear(perform: authState.signInAnonymously)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a child view that also uses the authState.isLoading Bool.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct SignInUpView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authState: AuthState
    @StateObject var viewModel: SignInUpViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if authState.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else if authState.authStateMode == .signedInWithEmail {
                HostPreviewView()
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(viewModel.heading)
                        .font(.title)
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                    if let error = authState.error { Text("\(error.localizedDescription)") }
                    TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
                        .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .padding()
                    SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
                        .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .padding()
                    Button(viewModel.signInUpBtnLbl) {signInUpBtnAction()}
                        .font(.title2)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Button(viewModel.signInUpModeBtnLbl) {
                        viewModel.mode.toggle()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signInUpBtnAction() {
        switch viewModel.mode {
        case .signIn: authState.signIn(email: viewModel.email, password: viewModel.password)
        case .signUp: authState.linkAccount(email: viewModel.email, password: viewModel.password)
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that whenever the isLoading Bool switches to true while on the child view, the UI presents the parent view.

Can someone shed some light on how best to go about solving this issue?

Comment: You have not provided enough code to diagnose this issue

Comment: My apologies. I am still getting the hang of how much/little to share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following code from your example:

```
if authState.isLoading == true {
                    ProgressView()
                } else if authState.authStateMode == .unregistered {
                    Button { authState.signInAnonymously() }
                        label:{ Text("Connect") }
                } else {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: GuestPreviewView(),
                        label: { Text("Join as Guest") })
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: SignInUpView(viewModel: .init(mode: .signUp)),
                        label: { Text("Host a Session") })
                }
```

If `authState.isLoading` is true, it presents the `ProgressView()`.  Then, later you have the `NavigationLink` to `SignInUpView`. The problem arises when `isLoading` is set to `true` when the user is on `SignInUpView` -- you expect it to render `ProgressView` on that page, but because the parent then switches to its own `if authState.isLoading` clause, it removes the `NavigationLink` that had presented to the child view from the hierarchy, kicking you back to the first page.

How you solve this is an architectural decision, and not necessarily a fix with one definitive answer. Perhaps the thing to ask is: do you need an `authState.isLoading` clause on the parent view? Can loading only happen on the child view page?

Probably simplest is to not wrap your NavigationLink in the `if/else` since I assume it should get shown on the front page no matter what (?)

Something like:

```
if authState.isLoading {
  ProgressView()
}
if authState.authStateMode == .unregistered {
  Button...
}
NavigationLink(destination: SignInUpView())...
```

The key is to make sure one way or another that your `NavigationLink` isn't wrapped in an if/else where the child view will get removed from the hierarchy when the auth state changes.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response. I really appreciate it.

I have actually been spending the last few days trying to read about different architectural approaches, but I have yet to wrap my mind around them.

I will take your advice to heart and keep on keeping on.

Thanks again!

Comment: After re-reading your answer, it led me to another question. isLoading is specific to SelectUserTypeView. However, its value (true or false) is based on the authStateMode enum inside of the authState environment object. Can you point me towards some information regarding how to configure view-specific variables (like isLoading) that are based on information in an environment object (like authStateMode)?

Comment: I don't know of an article specifically about that, but this is a good resource about when to choose StateObject vs ObservableObject vs EnvironmentObject: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/07/02/the-difference-between-stateobject-environmentobject-and-observedobject-in-swiftui/

Comment: A general practice I like to employ is having one source of truth (ie one state object) that gets passed/injected into my view hierarchy. Storing state in multiple places causes problems (as you've already seen). Aim for uni-directional data flow

Comment: Hi Zach -- I see that you're new here and your other question doesn't have an accepted answer, either. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting answers that help.

Comment: Done! I visited the blog you recommended, which proved to be very helpful. I found another resource that is very clear for beginners: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/coding-through-iteration-and-integration.html#.

Answer (score 0):

jnpdx explanation of the problem is correct.

First of all if your state should not be shared among views you should use `@ObservedObject` instead of `@EnvironmentObject`. But if you still insist on it you can do the following in your parent view:

replace the last else block in your parent view with this:

```
        Group {
           NavigationLink(
                destination: GuestPreviewView(),
                label: { Text("Join as Guest") })
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SignInUpView(viewModel: .init(mode: .signUp)),
                label: { Text("Host a Session") })
        }.opacity(authState.isLoading ? 0 : 1)
```

this will not remove the NavigationLink and thus keep you on your child view, but it will hide the buttons. You can also change the width and height to prevent it from eating up screen estate.

The cleaner solution would be again to use @ObservedObjects in your child views like this:

```
struct SignInUpView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var authState = AuthState()
    @StateObject var viewModel: SignInUpViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if authState.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to response in such detail. Much appreciated.

That is a great point regarding using ObservedObject. I will give that a go.